# Why doesnt my JSON file popup in my working directory when I run my function?

Tags: python, json, directory, auto-populate

The idea is for a JSON file to be created in the working directory with configured inputs in the `funct` function below. But the file is not created in the working directory with tag `w`. Any Idea as to why its not doing so? what is an alternative to this if there is no solution?

```
def funct(var):
   varTwo= {
        "varThree":[
            {
            } 
        ]
    }
    with open("temp.json", "w") as f:
       json.dump(varTwo, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: Did you call the function?

Comment: @fsimonjetz yeah the function is called. I have ran the code several times and still does not work. mind you, the code at large creates a different file type else where in the code. It might just be that specific function i believe.

Comment: What does "the file is not created in the working directory with tag `w`" mean?

Comment: Did you verify the working directory?

Comment: @martineau 'w' auto creates that file in the working directory.

Comment: @KlausD I dont think i had to. But no.

Comment: That "tag" is the `mode` parameter the `open()` function accepts. If you're not getting an error from calling the function, it probably created the file but not in a folder you expected (because you're using a relative file path, not an full one). i.e. The working directory isn't what you think.

Comment: @martineau ok how would i figure that out. I have been looking for it but cant seem to find it.

Comment: You can see what the current working directory is by printing the return value of `os.getcwd()`. If you want some specific directory you can add it to the file name or use `os.chdir()` to change the cwd to what you want.